# Https fails Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, https

I'm Having a strange problem browsing the web. I'm getting no connection using https (on Firefox).I get an error message saying:

"An error occured during a connection to www.google.dk. Security library failure. Error code: 
SEC_ERROR_LIBRARY_FAILURE"

http is working allright. Is it a problem concerning ssl ? Is something broken ?

I'm not sure but it may have come about as a result of an upgrade to Firefox 48.0...

The problem started a couple of days ago and has been there ever since.

I don't know if it's  related but I'm having problems with my wireless connection to
the scanner part of my printer (hp office jet 6700) too.

Tom

Comment: Has it always been like this or just happens since an hour or so? What exactly is the problem? You get error messages you could share?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include the reason why you think it is not working, for instance an error you get when trying to connect to an HTTPS website. Please tell us what happens when you try and how you know it has failed.